# How to have "Page Title" different than "Menu Title" in wordpress 3.0.3?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, customization

I'd like to have the home page have a menu title of "Home" and a different page title "What we can do for you". How to do this without going into code.

Is there any plug in to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a plugin if you're using the built in menus - in Appearance -> Menus, click on a menu item and you can change it's navigation label. The label is what shows in the menus.